# Enable custom logger on firebase javascript client

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I'm currently trying to setup a custom log function for firestore javascript client.

Some older post told me to use the following code:

```
firebase.database.enableLogging(function(message) {
        console.log("[FIREBASE]", message);
      });
```

First of all, enable logging without setting the log level does not work at all.
Last point, my custom console log seems to be never used!!!

The ultimate goal is to replace this console.log with an AppInsight.Trace.

Has anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 1):

The [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database#enablelogging)  still gives that example.

I just tested the sample [here](https://jsbin.com/hovoleh/8/edit?html,js,output) and it works for me.

```
firebase.database.enableLogging(function(msg) {
  console.log("[MINE]: "+msg)
});
```

(The rest of the code in that jsbin is irrelevant, it just happens to be an example I had lying around)